# Callinga column but error not exists even though column exists in the df

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apache-spark-sql, data-analysis

I am trying to plot a line graph with respect to years . I am calling the column from the dataframe but it can't see it i dont know why even though you will find in the screenshot that the column exists in the dataframe

Here i printed the df columns and the column itslef but still got the error

[image: 1]

Comment: You are filtering your data columns to exclude 'STANDINGSDAT' column, so it isn't available for ploting.   Since you are using this a your x axis, just move STANDINGDATE in to to the dataframe index,  `ranking_df.set_index('[[your column list here]]').plot()`.

Comment: I get what you say but this isn't the issue , it still cant read the STANDINSDATE column i dont know why , thanks

Comment: either don't move it to the index, i.e., discard the set_index line, or don't specify it explicitly as the x= value in the plotter; it already looks at the index to put x values from

Comment: Don't specify x nor y, let the dataframe structure determine the x comes from the indexes and y are the columns of your dataframe.

Comment: Can you please provide a [mre]? See [ask] for further guidance. Can you please [read about why text is better than images of text](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11107541) and then [edit] to convert your images of text into actual text? See [/editing-help#code](/editing-help#code) for how to format code blocks.